# ant build script fails on window using command prompt

Tags: ant

I downloaded latest version of ant and installed it using [this guide](http://openguider.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/)

I used the `ant` command to start build process and i got
`All features of the build script require Ant version 1.8.2. Please upgrade to 1.8.2 or remove all instances of 'overwrite=no' (and this fail task) from the build script to continue"`

This is snippet from my build.xml

```
<!-- Load in Ant-Contrib to give us access to some very useful tasks! -->
<!-- the .jar file is located in the tools directory -->
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${basedir}/build/tools/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

 <!-- Test for Ant Version Delete this task and all instances of `overwrite='no'` if you can't upgrade to 1.8.2-->
    <fail message="All features of the build script require Ant version 1.8.2. Please upgrade to 1.8.2 or remove all instances of 'overwrite=no' (and this fail task) from the build script to continue">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <contains string="${ant.version}" substring="1.8.2"/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
```

Even though I have v1.9.0, I get the fail message stating that i need 1.8.2 or to perform the overwrite=yes which i did but am unable to resolve. Do i need to only use v1.8.2?

Answer (score 0):

To require certain versions of Ant, use the [`<antversion>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antversion.html):

```
<project name="ant-antversion" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <fail message="This build script requires at least Ant version 1.8.2.">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <antversion atleast="1.8.2"/>
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```